# Prevent Overlapping div's in CSS

Tags: html, css, overlap

I'm trying to make a page with CSS where contents from divs don't overlap each other. When content overflows from the **main div** (the white area), scroll  bars appear and you can scroll over the contents of the sidebar and header (ignore the red line text ... this is just my debugging info).

I didn't separate the CSS from the HTML so I apologize for the messy layout. The style tags in divs are what I'm using to position the content on the page.

The code for this can be found at https://jsbin.com/gesuser/edit?html and also the bottom of this post.

How do I prevent the main div from scrolling over the header and sidebar? I could do this using frames but I would rather not use that old tech. :)

Should be like this: [image]
and not like this: [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: #133068;">
            <div id="appname" style="float: left;">
                <a href="index.php"><label style="position: relative; top: 12px; left: 5px; font: bold 20pt/22pt 'Syncopate', Arial, sans-serif; color: white;">Bluebook</label></a>
            </div>

            <div id="searchbar" style="position: fixed; float: right; top: 12px; right: 20px;">
                <form id="" name="form_Search_All" action="search.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" id="text_Search" style="width: 350px;" name="text_Search" placeholder=" search all departments" />
                    <input type="submit" name="btnSearch_All" value="+" />

                    <input type="radio" id="radio_Search_BB" name="radio_Search" value="BB" checked /><label style="color: white;">BB</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="radio_Search_RC" name="radio_Search" value="RC" /><label style="color: white;">RC</label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar grad" style="position: fixed; top: 50px; width: 200px; height: 100%; background-color: #4e6799; z-index: -1;">
            <div class="btn-group" style="position: relative; top: 20px;">
                <?php if ($site->IsAdmin ()) : ?>
                    <a href="logout.php"><button class="button">ADMIN LOGOUT</button></a>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <a href="login.php"><button class="button">ADMIN LOGIN</button></a>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <a href="index.php"><button class="button">SEARCH PAGE</button></a>
            </div>

            <div id="version" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; margin: 5px; font: bold 9pt/11pt Arial; color: #9a9797;">
                <label>Version 2.0.0</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 210px;">
            <?php $tpl->Component (); // this outputs tables of data ?>
        </div> <!-- main -->

    </div> <!-- container -->
```

Comment: Can you please show just the HTML and CSS in a demo? Somewhere hosted or using JSBin?

Comment: Why are you inlining your CSS in the DOM???

Comment: Ok. Here is the code on JSBin: https://jsbin.com/gesuser/edit?html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use absolute position for the main div. Use a relative and add margin to it:

```
<div class="main" style="position: relative; margin-top: 60px; margin-left: 210px;">
    <?php $tpl->Component (); // this outputs tables of data ?>
</div>
```